# Бот discord (discord.py) фильтр матов

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Ребят, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать такую штуку. У меня есть бот на discord. py. Он берет сообщение из чата, переводит в нижний регистр, убирает знаки препинания и сравнивает, есть ли сходство msg_words (нашего полученного слова) в списке ban_words. Все прекрасно, однако есть но. Например, у нас есть слово стол. Его можно написать так: стоАААл или так: сАААтол. При выполнении моей программы остается это: стоал или это сатол. Но ТАКОГО СЛОВА НЕТ В СПИСКЕ! Есть только стол. И поэтому мне надо, чтобы он находил схожесть полученного слова с banwords в ПРОЦЕНТАХ! и если оно больше 80%, то тогда программа выводила: Щас по губам отшлепаю!
Вот сама программа:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os, sqlite3
import string, json


ban_words = ["стол"]

def simplify_word(word):
    last_letter = ''
    result = ''
    for letter in word:
        if letter != last_letter:
            last_letter = letter
            result += letter

    return result

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return

       
    msg_words = [simplify_word(word.lower().translate(str.maketrans('','', string.punctuation))) for word in message.content.split()]


    for word in msg_words:
        if word in ban_words:
            try:
                await message.delete()
            except:
                print('Произошла ошибка при удалении слова! Проверь наличие прав у бота!')
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} **Щас по губам отшлепаю!**')
            return


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю вам стоит посмотреть в сторону регулярных выражений. Модуль re

Comment: Спасибо за предложения, я попробую это реализовать

Comment: Я хочу попробовать использовать diff, однако, я так понял, он работает только с string (а у меня множества msg_words и ban_words) мне бы хотелось сделать так:
    import difflib as dl
    for diff in dl.get_close_matches(msg_words, ban_words):
Однако это не работает